# UITextField on keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitextfield

Есть textField ,где пользователь должен ввести имя. Поскольку этот textField в низу на View , то я его поднял. Когда я нажимаю на него , textField поднимается на клавиатурой.

Проблема в том , что textField падает на место , когда  пользователь нажимает  что нибудь на клавиатура , а не держится над клавой пока та на экране

Вот код реализации.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var nameTextFieldOutlet: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 44))
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    nameTextFieldOutlet.inputAccessoryView = customView
    nameTextFieldOutlet.addLine(position: .LINE_POSITION_BOTTOMSet, color: .white, width: 1)
    nameTextFieldOutlet.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я для себя решил проблему что просто использую CenterNotification во viewDidLoad().Это Решение меня устраивает .

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification   ,  object: nil, queue: nil) {(nc) in
        self.view.frame.origin.y = -300
    }
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification  ,  object: nil, queue: nil) {(nc) in
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0.0
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в том что во время ввода данных медоты нотификаций которые вы используете могут вызываться много раз, поэтому более правильное решение будет сохранить константу высоты (если вы используете frame для изменения местоположения объекта, как по мне так лучше изменять constraint)

Попробуйте такой подход

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    let frameOriginTextField = nameTextFieldOutlet.frame.origin.y
    ...
}


@objc func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue //frame клавиатуры
        //Получем высоту клавиатуры
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        nameTextFieldOutlet.frame.origin.y = frameOriginTextField + keyboardHeight
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    nameTextFieldOutlet.frame.origin.y = frameOriginTextField
}
```

Comment: Есть несколько ошибок , не могу исправить только одну. В функциях ( keyboardWillShow, keyboardWillHide) выдаёт ошибку - Use of unresolved identifier 'frameOriginTextField'

Comment: let frameOriginTextField = nameTextFieldOutlet.frame.origin.y - этот параметр я создал во viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1):

Так как Вы не прикрепили как это выглядит, предположу что текстфилд виден постоянно и находится в нижней части экрана. Используйте его в качестве
[inputAccessoryView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621119-inputaccessoryview)

Ну и по Вашему решению, не отнимайте / прибавляйте к текущей константе constraint, задавайте ей требуемое значение при показе / сокрытии клавиатуры.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий . Я  написал такой код  и подключил текстовое поле. Но когда клавиатура подымается , custom view показывает , но текста не видно . Я обновил свой код